# How can I change the dir of the header image?

Tags: nsis, wizard

I have seen in all scripts when I have to change the image header that uses the `${NSISDIR}` like this:

```
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_RIGHT

!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP ${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\nsis-r.bmp
```

But I need to put the image in other folder to not depending of NSIS dir.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I can not depend of `/home/username` too.

I want that because the wizard can be compiled in any linux PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a relative path...

*Edit:*

Use a relative path when the .bmp is in the same folder tree as your .nsi:

```
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP .\mygfx\header.bmp
```

If you want to use one of the other NSIS images you should just use the NSISDIR define, the POSIX compiler will convert the path:

```
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP ${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\nsis-r.bmp
```

Comment: The path of my nsis script?

Answer (score 1):

You just use

```
Contrib\Graphics\Header\nsis-r.bmp
```

And folder Contrib is local to script place(folder)

Comment: The script should never be relative to the Contrib folder because that is inside the NSIS installation and you should not put your own scripts there...